# Datepicker in ajax page is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two pages main.php and ajx_receipt_sub_detail.php. 1 is th emain.php and another is an AJAX page to load the datepicker page ieajx_receipt_sub_detail.php .But datepicker is not working fine.But when I try to load it with an ajax call, the selector just seems not be working at all.Anybody give any solution for these issue?

main.php

```
function sub_detail(id)
{
var exchange_rate=$('#exchange_rate').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajx_receipt_sub_detail.php',
    data:'id='+id + '&exchange_rate=' + exchange_rate,
    success: function(msg)
     { 
      $("#sub_detail").html(msg);

     }
  });   
}
```

ajx_receipt_sub_detail.php

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

  $(function() {
  $( "#slip_date2" ).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
  });
  </script>
           <input name="slip_date" 
  style="width:81px;" type="text" class="txtfld"  id="slip_date2" value=""  />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in your `main.php`

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("body").on("click", "#slip_date2", function(){
            if (!$(this).hasClass("hasDatepicker"))
            {
               $( "#slip_date2" ).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
               $(this).datepicker("show");

            }
        });
 });
</script>
```